# Javascript not running on php page

Tags: javascript, php, sql

So I am making a web based application that needs to have the ability for an admin user to create sub users. I have the sql database working correctly when I create a user but the issue is that when I go ahead and add a user, it redirects me to a different php page. With the javascript running, it normally just says successful when I change password or change username. Here's the code.

```
<!-- create username -->
<form action="php_action/createUsername.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="createUsernameForm">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Username</legend>        

    <div class="createUsenrameMessages"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">New User</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameC" name="usernameC" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo $result['username']; ?>"/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="changePasswordMessages"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="npassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="npasswordC" name="npasswordC" placeholder="New Password">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpasswordC" name="cpasswordC" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $result['user_id'] ?>" /> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-loading-text="Loading..." id="createUsernameBtn"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Add User </button>

    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

here is the script

```
// create username
$("#createUsernameForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
var form = $(this);

var username = $("#usernameC").val();
var newPassword = $("#npasswordC").val();
var conformPasswordPassword = $("#cpasswordC").val();

if(newPassword == "" || conformPassword == "") {
    if(newPassword == "") {
        $("#npasswordC").after('<p class="text-danger">The Current Password field is required</p>');
        $("#npasswordC").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    } else {
        $("#npasswordC").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(".text-danger").remove();
    }
    if(conformPassword == "") {
        $("#cpassword").after('<p class="text-danger">The Conform Password field is required</p>');
        $("#cpassword").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    } else {
        $("#cpassword").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(".text-danger").remove();
    }


    return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false` at the end of the event binding means that the form won't be submitted.

Comment: @Barmar I have the same javascript code for another function for changing the password and it works fine with that

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced. Isn't there an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar I'm coding this in notepad++, Im very new to javascript

Comment: Javascript console = The browsers developer tools javascript console, not your editor. Here's a good post on how to access it in different browsers: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: GET http://198.199.106.22/stock/assests/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/canvas-to-blob.min.js');%20?%3E 404 (Not Found) , Okay so I know this error isn't related to my javascript. Thanks I will read it

Comment: When you're having trouble with Javascript, the **first** place you should look is the browser's console. It has a very powerful debugger, you should exhaust its resources before coming here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm not getting an error regarding to my code. Is there a more efficient way of developing this other than having to transfer my files through filezilla every time?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You could, for example, set up a local environment using Vagrant or similar.